# UIKit UIStackView with auto width

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm making an app with UIkit and I'm making some UITableViewCells that contain an array of user images. I want these images to be displayed in a horizontal stack and overlay each other.

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

That's how it looks:

[image]

Code:

```
    import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class CountryTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "CountryTableCell"

    //MARK: - Propeties
    var viewModel: CountryViewModel? {
        didSet {
            viewModel?.delegate = self
            setUpSpace(viewModel)
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: - SubViews
    private let container: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.withSize(CGSize(width: Dimensions.maxSafeWidth, height: 150))
        view.backgroundColor = .secondary_background
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        return view
    }()
    
    private let adminsContainer: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.withSize(CGSize(width: (Dimensions.maxSafeWidth - 32), height: Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay))
        view.backgroundColor = .secondary_background
        return view
    }()
    
    private let adminsStack: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.alignment = .leading
        stack.spacing = -10
        stack.sizeToFit()
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        stack.withSize(CGSize(width: Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay, height: Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay))
        return stack
    }()
    
    private let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title2).pointSize, weight: .bold)
        label.textColor = .primary_label
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()
    
    var headerView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.withSize(CGSize(width: Dimensions.image.headerSizeForCell.width, height: ((Dimensions.image.mediumHeigth/2) + Padding.horizontal)))
        iv.backgroundColor = .secondary_background
        iv.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        return iv
    }()
    
    //MARK: - Init
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        addSubview(container)
        container.center(inView: self)
        
        addSubview(headerView)
        headerView.anchor(top: container.topAnchor, left: container.leftAnchor, right: container.rightAnchor)
        
        addSubview(nameLabel)
        nameLabel.anchor(top: headerView.bottomAnchor, left: container.leftAnchor, right: container.rightAnchor, paddingLeft: Padding.horizontal, paddingRight: Padding.horizontal)
        
        addSubview(adminsContainer)
        adminsContainer.anchor(left: container.leftAnchor, bottom: headerView.bottomAnchor, right: container.rightAnchor ,paddingLeft: Padding.horizontal, paddingBottom: -(Dimensions.image.mediumHeigth/2), paddingRight: Padding.horizontal)
        bringSubviewToFront(adminsContainer)
        adminsContainer.backgroundColor = .clear.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
        adminsContainer.addSubview(adminsStack)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func willRemoveSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
        
    }
    
    //MARK: Selectors
    
    
    //MARK: - Helpers
    private func setUpSpace(_ viewModel: CountryViewModel?) {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel else {return}
        
        if let url = viewModel.country.headerImage?.url {
            headerView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url))
        }
        
        nameLabel.text = viewModel.space.name
    }
}

// MARK: Extension
extension SpaceTableCell: CountryViewModelDelegate {
    func didFetchAdmin(_ admin: User) {

        
        if let admins = viewModel?.admins.count {
            if admins == 1 {
                adminsStack.withSize(CGSize(width: Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay, height: Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay))
            } else if admins == 2 {
                adminsStack.withSize(CGSize(width: ((Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay*2) - 10), height: Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay))
            } else if admins == 3 {
                adminsStack.withSize(CGSize(width: ((Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay*3) - 20), height: Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay))
            } else if admins == 4 {
                adminsStack.withSize(CGSize(width: ((Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay*4) - 30), height: Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay))
            } else if admins == 5 {
                adminsStack.withSize(CGSize(width: ((Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay*5) - 40), height: Dimensions.image.mediumHeigthWithOverlay))
            }
        }
        
        let image = UserImageView(height: Dimensions.image.mediumHeigth)
        image.sd_setImage(with: admin.profileImageURL)
        adminsStack.addArrangedSubview(image)
    }
}


class UserImageView: UIImageView {
    
    //MARK: - Propeties
    let selectedHeigth: CGFloat
    
    init(height: CGFloat) {
        self.selectedHeigth = height
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: selectedHeigth, height: selectedHeigth))
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundColor = .secondary_background
        layer.cornerRadius = Dimensions.userImageCornerRadious(selectedHeigth)
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me

Thank you :)

Comment: The two images you posted are virtually identical. What issue are you having?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75223932/6257435

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a couple changes:

**Change #1**:

Your `UIStackView`'s `distribution` set to `.fillEqually`. By doing this, you're giving it the permission to stretch its `arrangedSubviews` as and when needed to fit the width that you've provided. This does prove useful in some cases but in your case, it's better to go with `.fill` instead

Here's an excerpt from Apple's documentation:

> For all distributions except the UIStackView.Distribution.fillEqually
> distribution, the stack view uses each arranged view’s
> intrinsicContentSize property when calculating its size along the
> stack’s axis. UIStackView.Distribution.fillEqually resizes all the
> arranged views so they’re the same size, filling the stack view along
> its axis. If possible, the stack view stretches all the arranged views
> to match the view with the longest intrinsic size along the stack’s
> axis.

I suggest that you go through [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) documentation and read more about this

**Change #2:**

Since you've now changed the `distribution` to respect intrinsic size, don't set up constraints that conflict with `UIStackView`'s distribution `axis`. In your case, you have a `horizontal` stack view and seem to be also defining its width constraints based on the number of admins you have. I'd suggest getting rid of it and leave it to your stack view to take care of it.

One more pointer:

Make sure your `UserImageView`s have proper unified `intrinsicContentSize` i.e: the images you set follow the same size. If doubtful, I'd suggest setting up constraints for its width and height respectively. To do so, in your `UserImageView`'s `init`, include:

```
self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
```